# JSLink: Return field value as plain text

Tags: 2013, rich-text, jslink

This might be really very simple,  I have a list view with multiple Rich Text fields,  I want to remove HTML formatting from those field in a specific view and return them as Plain text.

I would like to do it without using RegEx.  I am sure there must be any simple ways. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this considered a duplicate? [Similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) can be found on stack overflow, since the underlying question here is how to strip HTML formatting from text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler then i thought.  Implemented JSLink for the same...

```
(function () {

// Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it output render 
var viewContext = {};
viewContext.Templates = {};

viewContext.Templates.Fields = {
    "Field":{"View": renderPlainText}       
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(viewContext);})();
```

My render function looks like below:-

```
function renderPlainText(ctx) {
var value = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
value = value.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
return "<div>" + value + "</div>"; }
```

Comment: Your function uses regular expressions, which you said you did not want.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, all the other ways i found was implemented using SharePoint object model where we SPListItem class had a method for returning the value as plain text,  thought of going ahead with whatever i can find fast :)